# LibGDX File not found

Tags: libgdx, filenotfoundexception, tiled

Im trying to load a tiled map in libGDX with

```
tileMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("maps/level1.tmx");
```

but somehow it returns a File not found exception:

```
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: maps\level1.tmx (Internal)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.reader(FileHandle.java:164)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.XmlReader.parse(XmlReader.java:81)
... 9 more
```

I already tried to change the path to "/maps/level1.tmx" and other things but nothing works. It returns the file not found exception every time. Can someone see the error?

The path to the .tmx file is:

```
assets/maps/level1.tmx
```

the orginal assets folder is in the android project and in every project, the assets folder is linked..

Comment: Did you put it into your `assets` directory?

Comment: Yes ^^ Its in the assets folder in the android project and it also shows up in the assets folder of the desktop project.

Comment: What does the following say: Gdx.files.internal("maps/level1.tmx").file().getAbsolutePath(); and where does the file actually exist?

Comment: I copied the assets folder in the desktop project, used Gdx.files.internal("maps/level1.tmx").file().getAbsolutePath() and now it works :) thx

Comment: You should not use the absolute path, it isn't portable. I was just suggesting a way to determine if the path was actually what you were expecting it to be. Correcting the relative path is the proper fix.