# Tiled Map Editor exporting Libgdx

Tags: java, exception, libgdx

I have a problem with exporting Tiled map file.
I create map and , suggest a tutorial, I exporting tmx file and import it in Eclipse project assets.
In the code I did this:

```
tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("map.tmx");
tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap);
```

My problem is that when I execute it I get this :

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: tileset 2/grass-tiles-2-small.png
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare(FileTextureData.java:64)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load(Texture.java:130)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:121)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:100)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:96)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:116)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader.load(TmxMapLoader.java:101)
    at com.mygdx.game.MyGdxGame.create(MyGdxGame.java:43)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: tileset 2/grass-tiles-2-small.png (Internal)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:220)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
```

What do I for fix it?

Comment: "Couldn't load file", so *first thing to check* is if this file is in the location your code expects.

Comment: I can not figure out which file is not found. In the project I insert tmx file and nothing else.

Comment: You can't? What about the one mentioned in the first line?

Comment: I mean not that I do not know which file is but I do not know where to get this file. I export only tmx file and that file is missing I do not know what it is

Answer (score 0):

As I see in libGdx wiki , there is two option to load tmx files. Make sure your files under the assets folder. You can see in [libGdx Wiki how to load tmx files](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Tile-maps#loading-tmxtiled-maps). Also there is similar question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123681/libgdx-file-not-found).

Answer (score 0):

Tiled is referencing its tileset image source in the `.tmx` file. So the tileset `grass-tiles-2-small.png` you used is **not** embedded and has to be loaded, too. Fortunately this is done automatically by resolving the image dependencies for you.

So additionally to `map.tmx` you have to make sure that all used image files are reachable by copying them to your assets folder. It has to look like this: `assets/tileset 2/grass-tiles-2-small.png`. Refresh your Eclipse project after doing so, just in case it didn't notice.

If you already did that, another source of the problem could be the whitespace in your directory name. Try to rename `tileset 2` to `tileset_2` and create a new `.tmx` file.

Answer (score 0):

It simply failed to load you texture `grass-tiles-2-small.png`. I usually open up the `TMX/XML` file and set the filenames for the tilesheets to just the filenames manually without a path.

*Example:*

```
<tileset firstgid="1" name="grass" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32">
  <image source="grass-tiles-2-small.png" width="256" height="256"/>
 </tileset>
```

You should put the textures in the same folder within your project as the `map.tmx` resides preferably `Android/assets/../..` and use the `Gdx.files.internal` to load your map. `internal` just returns a regular file handle.

```
tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load(Gdx.files.internal("yourmap.tmx"));
```

The TMX just looks in the same folder for the right textures to use since we didn't specify a path in the tmx/xml.

*Thoughts:*
I really hate the `LibGDX` default `TmxLoader`. It would work for really simple things but you have no way of sorting depth when sprites overlap since the only way to draw is to draw a complete layer at once. If you need a overlap on a player you need to be able to draw tile by tile/object by object. I wrote my own `XML` parser for Tiled maps and it surprised me how simple it was. I have a pretty complicated map and it just took me about 30 lines of code to load everything into an array ready to draw it within `LibGDX`.